# Is it possible to run a single .c file in CLion

Tags: c, clion, jetbrains-ide

I have just downloaded CLion in Ubuntu Linux. I created a project called "MyCProject". I created a folder named "Random Stuff" and in that folder I created a file that prints "hello world".

Everything seemed to work fine but when I created another file that adds two numbers and prints the sum a problem arose: when I try to run it CLion finds multiple definitions of main. I tried to find a solution in JetBrains documentation, but I didn't find any.

I am sorry if this question is silly, but I am new to CLion and C programming in general. If you would like further information about the problem feel free to ask.

The error message:

```
====================[ Build | MyCProject | Debug ]==============================
/snap/clion/180/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/jason/CLionProjects/MyCProject/cmake-build-debug --target MyCProject
[1/1] Linking C executable MyCProject
FAILED: MyCProject 
: && /usr/bin/cc -g  CMakeFiles/MyCProject.dir/Random_Stuff/HelloWorld.c.o CMakeFiles/MyCProject.dir/Random_Stuff/AddTwoNumbers.c.o -o MyCProject   && :
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/MyCProject.dir/Random_Stuff/AddTwoNumbers.c.o: in function `main':
/home/jason/CLionProjects/MyCProject/Random Stuff/AddTwoNumbers.c:4: multiple definition of `main'; CMakeFiles/MyCProject.dir/Random_Stuff/HelloWorld.c.o:/home/jason/CLionProjects/MyCProject/Random Stuff/HelloWorld.c:3: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: create a `CMakeLists.txt` file read [this](https://medium.com/@onur.dundar1/cmake-tutorial-585dd180109b)

Comment: Or just create a new project and import your all C/C++ files into that project

Comment: I'm not so familiar with CLion in particular, but it is typical for an IDE to assume by default that all of the source files in a project are meant to be part of the same program.  You have (at least) two that seem to be meant to contribute to separate programs.  I expect that it would synergize best with CLion to have a separate project for each program.  That probably means a separate project folder for each one.  You will appreciate this more when you advance to programs built from multiple files.